# Trying to style a submit button seperate from other inputs

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

First of all, this is probably a stupid question, but I'm new and still figuring out CSS a bit. I'm trying out CakePHP and using its form helper to generate a form. It goes something like this:

```
<p><?php echo $this->Form->input('email');?></p>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('contact.gif');?>
```

Which produces:

```
<p>
    <div class="input text">
        <label for="CharityEmail">Email</label>
        <input name="data[Charity][email]" 
               type="text" 
               maxlength="255" 
               id="CharityEmail" />
    </div>
</p> 
<div class="submit">
    <input type="image" src="/raisin/img/contact.gif" />
</div>
```

In my CSS I want to give the input boxes a width of 255px, but if I do so, then the submit button gets made bigger too. Also, I'd like a border around the input boxes but not the submit button, which is a problem too.

Basically, how can I style the submit button differently? What's the proper way in CakePHP?

Comment: Isn't there a method in CakePHP for adding a CSS Class to the form element?

Comment: @jnpcl There sure is and I mentioned it below in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Here you are specifying the type as text.

```
input[type=text] { width:255px; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
input[type=text] {width: 255px;}
```

Or if you have to target IE6 it looks like you could use:

```
div.text input {width: 255px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to doing this specific to CakePHP is found below.  I would accomplish this by adding a `class` attribute to my input text element(s).

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'yourButtonClass'));
```

Then in your CSS file you would define the following:

```
.yourButtonClass { width: 255px; }
```